# How to give a custom view for the UIBarButtonItem that is shown on portrait mode for UISplitViewController?

Tags: ipad, uibarbuttonitem, uisplitviewcontroller

When we go portrait mode while using a UISplitViewController, they will provide us by a barButtonItem. How can I use a customView for that barButtonItem?

I tried the following way. It works if I start with portrait orientation. But if I go landscape and when I come back it crashes.

In viewDidLoad

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22.00, 22.00);    
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showHomeDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];    
homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[button release];
```

Then in willHideViewController

```
barButtonItem = homeButton;
```

What shud I do? OR is there an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView initWithImage:image];
homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];
[homeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showHomeDetails)];
[homeButton setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 22.00, 22.00)];
```

Hope this solves your problem
jrtc27

Comment: Antonio, ask it as a separate question - you will get more replies.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrote it like this inside the willHideViewController and its done.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"news.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height );    
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showSideTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
[barButtonItem setCustomView:button];
```

Main change is removed [button release].

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the target and action you add to the button. Can you post the implementation of the showSideTable method?

Comment: - (void) showSideTable
{
 [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[toolBar2.items objectAtIndex:2] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an image is the custom view you're looking for:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [barButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"awesome_menu_icon.png"]];
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
}
```